# singed apk not working (API is not Response)

Tags: android, apk, release

All network calls (RESTFUL APIs)implemented in my app are not working when I am uploading the app in play store since morning while it's working perfectly fine when building apk from system. And when I updated my app last time, it was working perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you implemented different urls for development,testing and in production? @Ashish?

Comment: install apk on your phone before uploading and test.